# converting an object to an array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I'm trying to compare two arrays and use the difference of them to remove data from another array but as I use the resulting array to do a array_diff_key using an array_flip it returns;
**array_diff_key(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given**

```
$unchecked_cols = array_diff($selected_table_cols,$selected_cols);
        $tem_array = [];                    
        foreach ($selected_table_data as $key => $value) {
            $value =array_diff_key($value, array_flip($unchecked_cols));
            $tem_array[$key] = $value;
        }
```

this is the code and I've tried converting the 'unchecked cols' to an array using toArray method but then i get:
**Call to a member function toArray() on array** error.
what should i do in a case like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert object to array you can add `(array)` before your object

```
$unchecked_cols = array_diff($selected_table_cols,$selected_cols);
$tem_array = [];                    
foreach ($selected_table_data as $key => $value) {
     $value =array_diff_key((array)$value, array_flip($unchecked_cols));
     $tem_array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked.... I tried many other things but i didn't think of that..

Comment: Glad to hear that!